# Using SUMIFS function to get total value on all revenues based on date selection

Tags: excel, sumifs

My aim is to add the revenue values in a single row, based on the Dates. The Revenue values from the Reporting date till the Project End date should be summed,

I have selected all Revenue cells in the same row and made it into a Rev_Range1......

My formula:

```
=SUMIFS(Date_Range1,Rev_Range1, ">=" &Resource_Profile_SOWNo!I8, Date_Range1, "<=" &Resource_Profile_SOWNo!I7)
```

where l8= Reporting Date, l7= End date,

I get a #VALUE!........in the cell where I put the formula. How can I fix my formula?

Comment: you inversed Date_Range1 and Rev_Range1 at the very beginning - your first argument should be the range you try tu summarize

Comment: =SUMIFS(Rev_Range1,Date_Range1,">=" &Resource_Profile_SOWNo!I8,Date_Range1,"<=" &Resource_Profile_SOWNo!I7)

Comment: tried with this...same result

Comment: The formula now seems correct, hard to try without more information. My guess is that one of your ranges is not formatted correctly (eg your dates are hardcoded)

Comment: Let me check on that Jo

Comment: Make sure your ranges are the same size.

Comment: I checked the ranges....well the full list of dates is not taken even when I ctrl and select those cells and try to give a new range name...is there a max cell limit in a range ?

Comment: and i am doing a range selection on the rows and not on Columns

Comment: Well , I again Checked...the sum range is for 37 cells.....and the Date range also for 37 cells......

The Revenue total cells need to be taken.....ie... the cell which has 6000 value, The Date cell is a single merged cell on top of this table....